# IOS Webview app

Tags: ios, uiwebview, simplecart

Here's my question, i have a UIWebview app that i have deployed for our companies sales force, problem i am having is the following, i use simple cart js and jotform to send the sales tickets back to the office, i have it setup so the app doesn't go to background on exit however items in the cart still remain when they reopen app, so i need to know if there is anyway to make the app revert to default everytime it opens or delete that stored information when opened?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: When you say: "i have it setup so the app doesn't go to background" What have you done ?

Comment: UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend in the Plist so when i press the home button the app completely closes and doesn't stay in the BG

Comment: The `xcode` tag should only be used for questions related to the IDE itself.

Answer (score 1):

To clear your `SimpleCart` cart call this:

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:"simpleCart.empty();"];
```

Documentation:

- [simpleCart.empty()](http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/simplecart-empty)
- [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a)

Comment: called it but cart still appears when app is re-opened

Comment: is there any code or command that will restore the app to its original settings (as in when its first installed) every time its closed?

Comment: normally, you get this with `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` set to `YES`

Comment: i am using the exitsonsuspend and it is working but on reopening the app it starts at the initial "welcome" page but the items in the cart from the previous order are still in the cart which is where i am stuck

Comment: try to delete the local webview data like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13223746/2115477